# how to convert AM/PM to 24 hour timestamp format in Vertica?

Tags: vertica

I have some rows that were loaded from the data file to table A that is having all columns with varchar type.
But while moving these rows from the initial table to the final merge table I want to cast the time value to 24-hour type. I am doing it as below:

select to_TIMESTAMP('12-FEB-21 01.00.44.720000 AM','DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS.MS');

But the above statement fails to convert AM to 24 hours time accordingly.

Can someone please guide me on where am I doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
sbx=> select to_TIMESTAMP('12-FEB-21 01.00.44.720000 AM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.US AM')
           , to_TIMESTAMP('12-FEB-21 01.00.44.720000 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.US AM');
      to_TIMESTAMP      |      to_TIMESTAMP
------------------------+------------------------
 2021-02-12 01:00:44.72 | 2021-02-12 13:00:44.72
```